# PHP - Generate HTML Select Menu without duplicates

Tags: php

I'm retrieving a list of records from a database and then looping through them to b build an HTML Select menu. However the records can contain duplicate entries so I would like to only show the unique entries.

Here's my PHP code to build the select menu:

```
<?php
    foreach($records as $record) {
     $category = $record->getField('category');
     echo '<option value="'. $category .'">'. $category .'</option>';
    } 
?>
```

I need to include some logic to compare the select menu with each new record that I'm adding to the list to ensure that it doesn't already exist in the list, but not sure how to go about this.

Update: I started experiment with creating an array instead and found that the following:

```
foreach($records as $record) {
      $category = $record->getField('category');
      $categories[$category] = $category;
    } 
 foreach($categories as $cat) {
 echo '<option value="'. $cat .'">'. $cat .'</option>';
}
```

generates a select menu with only the unique items. I'm new to PHP so just trying to understand this - does creating the Array automatically remove any duplicates?

Comment: You can either fix your query or use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and restructure your code a bit.

Comment: Thanks - I looked into creating an array following your comment and that appears to have removed the duplicates as a result. Is that expected behaviour? (see my update above)

Comment: Your update works as expected because `$k` in this expression `$array[ $k ] = ...` is a key, guaranteed to be unique. (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)). Just as an example, you could have written the first `foreach` as:  `$categories = array_unique( array_map( function($r){ return $r->getField("category"); }, $records) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my side, I'll just update my query to just display unique records by `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.
But if u don't want that, here's what will I do.

#### 1st Approach

```
<?php
    $listed_categories = [];
    foreach($records as $record) {
      $category = $record->getField('category');
      if( ! in_array( $category, $listed_categories ) {
         $listed_categories[] = $category;
         echo '<option value="'. $category .'">'. $category .'</option>';
      }
      
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - just tried that and still showing the duplicates (there was a missing ) in the line:       if( ! in_array( $category, $listed_array ) {

Comment: Sorry about that. Change the $listed_array to $listed_categories. I already updated the post. Typo Error. :)